# Есть ли возможность в Яндекс.переводчик API сделать автоопределение переводимого языка?

Tags: python, яндекс-переводчик

Есть ли возможность в `'lang'` в качестве первого аргумента указать автоопределение? Если да, то как ?

```
`trans_option = {'key':token, 'lang':'en-ru', 'text': text_translet}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Направление перевода может задаваться в виде кода конечного языка (например `ru`). В этом случае сервис пытается определить исходный язык автоматически.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests


url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate'
token = '[token]'

options = {'key': token, 'lang': 'ru', 'text': 'hello'}
response = requests.get(url, params=options).json()

print(response['text'][0])
```

***stdout:***

```py
привет
```